# Are there any travel agents forums? (experts in corporate travel US market)

Tags: online-resources, terminology, travel-agents

Does anyone know any travel agents forums and groups that I can ask very technical questions? 
I am looking to find answers on BSP/ARC and Sabre/Galileo commands regarding an exchange process.

Comment: FlyerTalk.com attracts a few TAs and ex-TAs. But it is not a dedicated travel agents' forum.

Comment: Are you a travel agent yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was noted, TSE is not the right venue for you, so you might want explore those that more closely coincide with your interest. Here are some results from a google search, in no particular order:

- TravelWeekly.com [Forum/Letters](http://www.travelweekly.com/ForumsLetters)
- HomeTravelAgent.net [forum](http://hometravelagent.net/wp/)
- TRO: [TravelResearchOnline.com](http://www.travelresearchonline.com/blog/)
- HBTANetwork.ning.com [Travel Professional Community](http://hbtanetwork.ning.com/)
- CCRA.com [Travel Commerce Network](https://www.ccra.com/home-based-travel-agent-forum/)
- Travel Agent Forum on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/homebasedtravelagentforum/)
- TravelSMG.com [Travel Show Marketing Group](http://www.travelsmg.com/travel-industry-events/)